# Recording 2-4 live video feeds in sync

Tags: video, recording, sync

I would like to video record my (and my friends') soccer match. I've bought a Chinese mini DV cam that I attach on top of the door and record on an SD card. But I want to do more: I would like to record using 2-4 wireless IP cam, and have a synchronized video in a grid side by side.

Which software can I use? And what kind of hardware would I need to record 2-4 live video files?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need great quality and are ok with ip camera quality footage (which it sounds like you are), you could pick up several wireless ip security cameras and connect them via WiFi on the same network as a Mac laptop running [Security Spy](http://www.securityspy.com/).